# How to shutdown a remote progress (openedge) database

Tags: database, openedge, progress-db

I want to shutdown a remote DB with proshut

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P20918

i get this error:

"Shutdown request denied because you are an invalid user, remote shutdown is not allowed, or the database is enabled for Failover Clusters. (12566)"

Where can i define the user for the shutdown request?

Comment: As the knowledgebase article suggests, only either a database owner or an account with which DB is started or the root account can only shut down a database remotely. Does your user account satisfy any of those conditions?

Comment: I have started my DB with Openedge Explorer, i also tried to add accounts wich match my windows login and started the DB with this one, nothing worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing the error because the database was started with the specific flag to disallow remote shutdown. Since you're probably not root, you will not be able to go around that.

More info on the normtshutdown db flag:

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P94213

Comment: Database is not on a cluster and not started with normtshutdown

Answer (score 0):

dbman -stop -H 192.168.1.123 -port 20931 -u j.verne -db pool_05_xyz
followed by my windows password stops the remote DB
(i dont know why this works...)

The problem seems to be that OpenEdge Explorer starts the DB with SYSTEM and not the user that is logged in.
When i try to stop it remotely my windows login name is used to send it as user to the server. At the moment i dont know how to solve it.
Maybe i can stop the db with DBMAN command, but this rejects my login.

Starting the service with a user account makes it possible to connect and stop it

AdminService for OpenEdge 11.4 Manages Progress OpenEdge servers Wird ausgeführt Automatisch j.verne@treasureIsland.de

But this is my local solution, i dont know if this is ok for the real remote server